# Kill session и ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

Ситуация такая, может кто сталкивался. В силу обстоятельств писал программку для себя в Visual Studio 2008 на C#  с использованием OracleDataProvider for .NET. Для этого скачал с сайта Oracle ODAC112021Xcopy_32bit и копирнул набор библиотек в проект. Суть вот в чем, как обработать ситуацию, если произойдет обрыв соединения(скажем, kill session) между этапами открытия соединения и запросом на чтение, т.е.

```
conn.Open(); 
//организуем запрос
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

При проверке такого случая программа у меня просто схлопывалась на ExecuteReader.

Comment: А где у Вас `conn.Open()` ?

Comment: Так проверять надо перед выполнением запроса, открыто ли у вас соединение. И в каком оно состоянии, а то вдруг вы там с другого потока читаете данные. Если поток один то надо проверять и восстанавливать соединение. а по хорошемц каждый раз открывать и закрывать после работы коннекшн.

Comment: Я как раз за этим и пишу, если оборвать соединение, его статус так и останется Open, и ошибок нету, просто схлопывание на строке ExecuteReader.

Comment: Ну ладно, я понял, что в идеале, нужно, открыть соединение, выполнить запрос и закрыть, и так каждый раз. Но все же, что если сессию убить в момент между открытием и выполнением, как тогда быть?

Comment: А программа у вас точно "схлопывается" или там обычное исключение вылетает?

Comment: Оно самое, из-за ряда алертов сбился с пути -_- вопрос снят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что Вам необходимо использовать блок [try-catch-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dszsf989.aspx) или [try-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx). К примеру будет выглядеть вот так:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{ 
  try
  {
    // Ваш код...
    conn.Open();
    // Ваш код...
    cmd.ExecuteReader():
    // Ваш код...
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  { 
    // либо обрабатываем исключение 
    // либо ничего не делаем - можно вообще убрать блок 'catch'
  }
  finally
  {
    conn.Close(); // закрываем соединение
  }
}
```

Полезные ссылки:

1. [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)
2. Блоки [try-catch-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dszsf989.aspx) и [try-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)
3. [.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)
4. [OracleCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ab4kxd8h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Лучше, конечно, помещать `OracleConnection` в [оператор using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx), ведь он [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), чтобы потом явно не вызывать метод `Dispose()`, а ведь про него можно и забыть в таком случае.

### Пример с сайта MSDN:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

> С помощью блока finally можно выполнить очистку всех ресурсов, выделенных в блоке try, и можно запускать код даже при возникновении исключения в блоке try.  Как правило, операторы блока finally выполняются, когда элемент управления покидает оператор try.

Comment: " метод Dispose()" а его нужно вызывать, что изменится, если не вызывать? спасибо.

Comment: @3per, прикрепил пару ссылок в ответе, ну если быть более конкретным: *освобождает неуправляемые ресурсы*. Если не используешь `using`, то должен явно вызвать метод `Dispose()`.

Comment: Хммм....проблема в том, что у меня нету никаких ошибок вообще, обо всем этом я знал и уже пробовал, думал как еще можно вырулить. Библиотеки вроде копировал все, какие нужно, но уже не уверен. Если запрос ничего не вернет или сессия будет убита, на ExecuteReader программа просто схлопывается.

Comment: @Вопрошающий, я не совсем понял значение *схлопывается*... Исключение - это не ошибка.

Comment: Все, извиняюсь за кипиш, поправил блок try..catch и все норм стало, видимо мысли перемешались, что делал, что сделал -_-.
P.S. Я правильно понимаю, что держать соединение Open все время нельзя, ибо это контр продуктивно?

Comment: @Вопрошающий, верно, все время держать соединение открытым - не правильно. Открывайте и закрывайте по мере надобности.

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз ивиняюсь за свою невнимательность, давно не кодил, особенно в студии -_-

Comment: @Вопрошающий, именно для этого и существует SO, чтобы помочь разобраться с возникающими трудностями и найти ответ. Всегда пожалуйста, рад, что смог Вам помочь!

Comment: @Denis Bubnov,Теперь только вопрос, как избавиться от размножения сессий, если эту конструкцию в цикл поместить -_-

Comment: @Вопрошающий, цикл должен быть внутри открытия соединения, но в блоке `try`. В комментариях не совсем удобно обсуждать - думаю, что Вам стоит задать новый вопрос.